# How to extract frequent itemsets from a column in a CSV file with Orange3?

Tags: python, csv, orange

The frequent itemset widget in Oragne3 expects its input from a File widget. The file containing the “transactions” is supposed to be a *basket* like in the example:

```
Bread, Milk
Bread, Diapers, Beer, Eggs
Milk, Diapers, Beer, Cola
Bread, Milk, Diapers, Beer
Bread, Milk, Diapers, Cola
```

But my file actually has a column with a user id and a second column with the actual transaction, something like this:

```
XYZ001, "Bread, Milk"
XYZ002, "Bread, Diapers, Beer, Eggs"
XYZ003, "Milk, Diapers, Beer, Cola"
XYZ004, "Bread, Milk, Diapers, Beer"
XYZ005, "Bread, Milk, Diapers, Cola"
```

How can I pass the transaction (second column) to the frequent itemset widget?

Answer (score 0):

Transform your basket file like this:

```
user=1, Bread, Milk
user=2, Bread, Diapers, Beer, Eggs
user=3, Milk, Diapers, Beer, Cola
user=4, Bread, Milk, Diapers, Beer
user=5, Bread, Milk, Diapers, Cola
```

Then do whatever you want to (i.e. strip) the `user` column?

Comment: Good point! It can be done even easier with the Excel "Text to Columns" command under the data tab, where you can select the comma as a separator.